# Storyboard error on iPhone5s, working on iPhone5

Tags: ios, iphone, uistoryboard

My project gives an error like this when i try to run on iphone5s.

```
terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 
'Storyboard  (<UIStoryboard: 0x7ffe90414500>) doesn't contain a view controller with 
identifier 'galleryPageViewController''
```

What might be wrong, which property might not be compatible with iPhone5s?

Comment: error it self said that can't fined identifier of galleryPageViewcontroller. check Properly in to the story Bord have correct identifier or not

Comment: is not the device problem here identifier "galleryPageViewController" is the problem check the identifier is correct or not

Comment: @NitinGohel if there is no proper identifier on the storyboard, it should also not work on iPhone5, but it does

Comment: that error related identifier sir. might be something goes wrong with you xcode.:) bcz error is identifier related

Comment: I had a similar issue once that was fixed by doing a full clean. Xcode is almost perfect at updating build files but not quite.

Comment: @PeterDeWeese do you recommend any step by step moving while cleaning? i did a full clean, still the same

Comment: i have fixed the issue by using storyboard assigning to a new object instead of self.storyboard, even they were in the same storyboard

Comment: Please post your fix as an answer instead of as a comment and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have fixed the issue by using

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" withBundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier@"MyViewController"];
```

it was before

```
[self.storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier@"MyViewController"];
```

somehow it confuses about the storyboards, now it works.